# Closed without isolated points implies regular closed?

Tags: general-topology

Let $F$ be a nonempty closed set of reals without isolated points.

> **Question.** Is it possible that $F$ is not regular closed?

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Regular_Closed_Set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set). This is closed, has no isolated point and has empty interior. Therefore the Cantor set is not regular closed.